# Issues while Creating an instance of the Uri class to hold the base address of the WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have created separate solutions as follows:

1. Solution A - that defines and implement the service contract for service R with interface IR and project name is ALib.
2. Solution B - host the service contract and runs it.

When I run the host application, it runs fine, but I cannot access the url with the base address provided. I updated the App.config file as instructed inside 
[WCF Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-and-run-a-basic-wcf-service)

Lets break down what has been updated inside the App.config file.

```
1. <service name="ALib.R"> 
2. <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/A/R" />
3. <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ALib.IR">
```

When I type the url "http://localhost:8000/A/R" I get HTTP 400 error, but I get the page with "http://localhost:8000/A/". This is not how it is done inside the tutorial. I have enabled the metadata as well follows:

```
            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
            {
                HttpGetEnabled = true
            };
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
```

Is there anything missing from what being done so far ?

Comment: I think the config should be `<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ALib.IR">` and `<add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/A" />` as you want to use the base address for multiple service

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Server6.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Server6.IService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="Server6.IService"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:13050/A/R"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"></serviceMetadata>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.